# how to use the NOT operator ~ in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I am creating a notebook and at some point I need to create a boolean mask. I use pandas version 17.1.

That is, I generate

```
mask=df.var.str.contains('hello')
```

However, it seems that I am unable to use the logical operator NOT `~` in ipython notebook, so `~mask` generates an error `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`

Actually, running `~False` in a cell gives me: -1

What is happening here?

Comment: sorry about this unfortunate variable name. In my example, the variable is actually called myvariable. So no confusion with var possible

Comment: Works for me. Please post a [mcve] that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: You probably have NaNs in `df.myvariable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I indeed was unable to run your code, but not because of `~` and not because of the notebook - the `.var` notation does something you do not expect.

This works fine:

```
mask=df['var'].str.contains('hello')
~mask
```

However, note this:

```
>>> type(df.var)
instancemethod
```

---

In general, when using the dot notation, you have to consider collisions between names and preexisting methods. You'd have a similar problem with a column named `size`, for example.

Comment: I'd use `~` too. For posterity sake, if you want regex-only solution, you could do negative lookbehind regex test - `df['var'].str.contains(r'^(?:(?!hello).)*$')`

Comment: Thanks, @JohnGalt - still don't know who you are, though :-)